# Using geom_line from ggplot2 (stat = summary) gives error?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my input data:

```
head(pf, 2)
   userid age dob_day dob_year dob_month gender tenure friend_count friendships_initiated likes likes_received mobile_likes
1 2094382  14      19     1999        11   male    266            0                     0     0              0            0
2 1192601  14       2     1999        11 female      6            0                     0     0              0            0
```

And here is my code:

```
ggplot(aes(x = age, y = friend_count), data = pf) +
    geom_jitter(alpha = 1/20) + xlim(13,90) +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.05, position = position_jitter(h=0), color = 'orange') +
    coord_trans(y = 'sqrt') +
    geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun.y = mean) +
    geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun.y = quantile, fun.args = list(probs = .1), linetype = 2, color = 'blue') +
    geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun.y = quantile, fun.args = list(probs = .5), color = 'blue') +
    geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun.y = quantile, fun.args = list(probs = .9), linetype = 2, color = 'blue')
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
Error in if (zero_range(range)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Removed 4906 rows containing non-finite values (stat_summary). 
2: Removed 4906 rows containing non-finite values (stat_summary). 
3: Removed 4906 rows containing non-finite values (stat_summary). 
4: Removed 4906 rows containing non-finite values (stat_summary). 
5: In trans$transform(out$range) : NaNs produced
```

How do I resole these issues?

Comment: you may have NAs in your df. Try `any(is.na(pf$age))` and `any(is.na(pf$friend_count))`, if one at least is TRUE, then you may need to omit NAs first with `ggplot(..., data=na.omit(pf))`?

Comment: I tried to improve wording/formatting of your question. But I think you want to carefully review the current content (for example the data example looks weird) to ensure that your readers get all required information in a nicely, easy to read layout.

Comment: any(is.na(pf$age)) and any(is.na(pf$friend_count)) both return FALSE. i removed some columns to make it more readable in the data example.

Comment: @eddd83 what will you get if you try `stat ="identity"`?

Comment: Please include some data in your question (using `dput()`) with which we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have negative values in your data? If so, that's the cause of your problem.

You're applying a square-root transformation to your data with `coord_trans(y='sqrt')`, but the square root of a negative number is an imaginary containing *`i`* (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit).

We can see this in a simplified example. This function plots normally:

```
ggplot(cars, aes(x=speed, y = dist)) +
    geom_point() +
    coord_trans(y = 'sqrt')
```

But if we multiply `cars` by `-1` to get negative values we replicate your error.

```
ggplot(-1 * cars, aes(x=speed, y = dist)) +
    geom_point() +
    coord_trans(y = 'sqrt')

Error in if (zero_range(range)) zero_width else diff(range) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In trans$transform(out$range) : NaNs produced
```

So, what can you do? That depends on what your data is and why you chose to do a `sqrt` transformation on it. You could take the absolute value first, or choose a transformation that is compatible with negative values, for example.